# I want to load all of the unit-tests in a tree, can it be done?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a heirarchical folder full of Python unit-tests. They are all importable ".py" files which define TestCase objects. This folder contains thousands of files in many nested subdirectories and was written by somebody else. I do not have permission to change it, I just have to run it.

I want to generate a single TestSuite object which contains all of the TestCases in the folder. Is there an easy and elegant way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The **nose** application may be useful for you, either directly, or to show how to implement this.

http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/ seems to be the home page.

Basically, what you want to do is walk the source tree (`os.walk`), use `imp.load_module`
to load the module, use `unittest.defaultTestLoader` to load the tests from the module into a `TestSuite`, and then use that in whatever way you need to use it.

Or at least that's approximately what I do in my custom `TestRunner` implementation
(`bzr get http://code.liw.fi/coverage-test-runner/bzr/trunk`).

Answer (score 2):

Look at the unittest.TestLoader (https://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#loading-and-running-tests)

And the os.walk (https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#files-and-directories)

You should be able to traverse your package tree using the TestLoader to build a suite which you can then run.

Something along the lines of this.

```
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
superSuite = unittest.TestSuite()
for path, dirs, files in os.walk( 'path/to/tree' ):
    # if a CVS dir or whatever: continue
    for f in files:
        # if not a python file: continue
        suite= unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromModule( os.path.join(path,f)
        superSuite .addTests(suite ) # OR runner.run( suite)
runner.run( superSuite )
```

You can either walk through the tree simply running each test (`runner.run(suite)`) **or** you can accumulate a `superSuite` of all individual suites and run the whole mass as a single test (`runner.run( superSuite )`).

You don't need to do both, but I included both sets of suggestions in the above (untested) code.

Answer (score 1):

The test directory of the [Python Library source](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/test/) shows the way.
The [README](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/test/README?view=markup) file describes how to write Python Regression Tests for library modules.

The [regrtest.py module](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/test/regrtest.py?view=markup) starts with:

```
"""Regression test.

This will find all modules whose name is "test_*" in the test
directory, and run them.
```